# Benchmark with Goroutines

Tags: go, benchmarking, goroutine

Pretty new to the Golang here and bumped into a problem when benchmarking with goroutines.

The code I have is here:

```
    type store struct{}
    
    func (n *store) WriteSpan(span interface{}) error {
        return nil
    }
    
    func smallTest(times int, b *testing.B) {
        writer := store{}
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        numGoroutines := times
        wg.Add(numGoroutines)
        b.ResetTimer()
        b.ReportAllocs()
        for n := 0; n < numGoroutines; n++ {
            go func() {
                writer.WriteSpan(nil)
                wg.Done()
            }()
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
    func BenchmarkTest1(b *testing.B) {
        smallTest(1000000, b)
    }
    
    func BenchmarkTest2(b *testing.B) {
        smallTest(10000000, b)
    }
```

It looks to me the runtime and allocation for both scenario should be similar, but running them gives me the following results which are vastly different. Wonder why this happens? Where do those extra allocations come from?

> BenchmarkTest1-12     1000000000           0.26 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
>
> BenchmarkTest2-12     1   2868129398 ns/op       31872 B/op         83 allocs/op
>
> PASS

I also notice If I add a inner loop to `writeSpan` multiple times, the runtime and allocation kind of relates to the `numGoroutines * multiple times`. If this is not the way how people benchmark with goroutines, are there any other standard ways to test? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The benchmark doesn't make any sense without doing some work incremented by `b.N`. Are you trying to benchmark the overhead of dispatching goroutines?

Comment: Hi! Goroutines does have a cost. They are not that expensive though. I am not an expert in the internals of Go, but I do know that each goroutine should have at least 2kb of allocation.

I think that what could be happening when you pass a certain amount of goroutines,  more memory has to be allocated just for storing the goroutine structure.

Comment: @JimB I tried version with b.N and update the waitGroup.add(b.N * numGoroutines) , the pattern is similar: once the (numGoroutines * numWrites) goes over a threshold, the code spends extra memory/time for benchmarking.

Comment: @Jamillo Santos I think your description makes more sense to me and it is indeed what I observed so far. Given that, is there a good threshold of (numGoroutines x numOperations per goroutine) we should avoid to cross?

Comment: Is there some kind of formatting glitch in your results, or did you really measure `0.26 ns/op` for the fast version?  That's ~1 clock cycle, so maybe something compiled to an empty asm loop that just increments a counter?  But `2868129398 ns/op` sounds barely plausible.  2.8 seconds per operation?  If 83 allocs / op is right, though, then copying all the memory for an array of tasks could explain it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think that error is due to @Jude not using `b.N`. Although, `b.N` is way lower than `numGoroutines` causing the miscalculation.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is what I observed which seems odd to me too.... Notice I didn't even add the loop with `b.N`, but the benchmark still runs for 1000000000 rounds..

Comment: This is a misuse of the benchmarking vacility, and calling your function with `b.N` as a parameter is equally wrong. You need to execute your function `b.N` times, *with the same parameters each time*, to get any kind of accurate results - though this is such a microbenchmark that even basically *accurate* results still would not be *useful*. See the documentation for a clear example: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks

Comment: @Adrian: How do you know what the OP wanted to learn from the results?  Maybe they wanted to understand the benchmarking system and/or goroutine machinery better by microbenchmarking *it* for pathological cases.  Obviously this result has some logical explanation in terms of the asm instructions the CPU ultimately ran.

Comment: I don't know, and it doesn't matter; whatever they wanted to learn, they won't learn anything from the quoted benchmark, for the reasons stated.

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, that's a helpful response, unlike the only answer currently.  It would be interesting to have an answer of exactly why we get these results when breaking the system this way.  Sometimes you can learn interesting implementation details by examining how things break when you use them wrong.  If I knew Go at all, I might write such an answer like I have for some asm / C undefined behaviour questions.

Answer (score 5):

**Meaningless microbenchmarks produce meaningless results.**

---

> If this is not the way how people benchmark with goroutines, are there
>   any other standard ways to test?

It's not the way to benchmark anything. Benchmark real problems.

You run a very large number of goroutines, which do nothing, until you saturate the scheduler, the machine, and other resources. That merely proves that if you run anything enough times you can bring a machine to its knees.

Comment: I think the real benchmark would have more stuff on it. Probably the guy was getting strange results because of the number of goroutines. Then, he was stripping things off until getting almost nothing on it.

Comment: @JamilloSantos: That is debugging, not benchmarking.

Comment: @peterSO this is indeed a concise version, but in my real benchmark code, I did have some other logics executed there. But I'm noticing the similar results: when the goroutines number is small benchmark is lightning fast but once I increase it to a certain number, everything changes. If you want, I can share with you the real code.  Are you suggesting that one should never test the threshold too high?